# simple tmux bash script not working

Tags: bash, tmux

I want tmux to open a new window and then cd into a directory, but it doesn't work. It just opens tmux in the directory my script was run from (ie. it doesn't execute the cd command).

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? (I'm using tmux 1.6)

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                             
tmux start-server
tmux new-session -d -s my_server -n runstuff

tmux send-keys -t my_server:1 "cd /etc"

tmux select-window -t my_server:1
tmux attach-session -t my_server
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I finally got it to work, using C-m and numbering the windows starting from 0. I added a second command for illustrative purposes.

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                             
tmux start-server
tmux new-session -d -s my_server -n runstuff
tmux new-window -t my_server:1 -n someotherjunk

tmux send-keys -t my_server:0 "cd /etc" C-m
tmux send-keys -t my_server:1 "./yolo" C-m

tmux select-window -t my_server:runstuff
tmux attach-session -t my_server
```

Comment: You can omit the `start-server` here, it it not required; the server it starts would immediately exit since you do not create any sessions from that same `tmux` shell command. You could do `start-session \; new-session …` to issue multiple *tmux* commands in a single shell command, but there is no need for that since `new-session` will start the server if there is not one already running. The other command that automatically starts a server is `attach-session` (which is only useful if you create sessions in your configuration file).

Answer (score 1):

`send-keys` simulates typing at the keyboard. As such, you need to send the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key as well.

```
tmux send-keys -t my_server:1 "cd /etc\n"
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried that, but it still doesn't seem to be executing the cd command. I just end up in a tmux window in the same directory as where I ran the bash script.

Comment: ok I realized that I should have been using :0 instead of :1. But now all I end up with is a tmux window with "cd /etc\n" typed in. The \n is being treated literally, not as an Enter key.

Comment: ah, adding C-m at the end of the send-keys line seemed to work. `tmux send-keys -t my_server:1 "cd /etc" C-m`

Comment: Sorry about that; I was going to suggest `C-m`, but tried `\n` and it worked for me. Maybe a version difference issue? Glad it's working now!